# Difference in interval notation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

What is the difference between these two exercise questions (regarding the intervals)?

1. Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $[\epsilon, \infty)$
2. Show that $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent on $(0, \infty)$

I mean in the first interval we don't have the 0 because $\epsilon > 0$ and in the second we don't have the 0 because it is an open interval.

So what is the difference?

Comment: In 1., you don't have zero but also you don't have numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to zero. Surely your functions $f_1, f_2, \dots$ do something interesting near $x=$ zero

Comment: @311411 But $\epsilon$ could be arbitrarily close to 0 - no?

Comment: Yes, but when you work part 1., you will leave epsilon fixed (and unspecified). So as you work part 1., there will always be a little space $(0,\epsilon)$ that you need not worry about. (Need not worry about inputs $x\in (0,\epsilon)$ for *every* function $f_n$.)

Comment: I did not study it carefully, but this looks like it may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3349773

Comment: You don't have $\epsilon /2$ in the first interval, but you do in the second.

Comment: What are the $f_n$s? For example, if $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx}$, these get infinitely steep near zero but if you they are defined on $[\epsilon,\infty)$, they get chopped off and will have a maximum absolute slope.

Answer (score 2):

[I gave a glib answer above as a comment, but hopefully this answer will give you some actual insight. :-} ]

For a cartoon version that might make the difference easier to see, replace "$f_n$ is uniformly convergent on" with "we can find a positive number that is strictly less than all numbers in".

What happens here, and probably what happens in your exercise, is that the truth of the statement requires you to find some number such that .... something is true about it. In a question like yours, about a sequence converging, I'll bet that you have to find some $N$ such that for all $i \gt N$ .... something holds.

So for each $\epsilon \gt 0$ you can find such an $N$ - and from now on I'm going to write it as $N_{\epsilon}$ to emphasize that it depends on $\epsilon$. But as your $\epsilon$ gets smaller, $N_{\epsilon}$ gets bigger and grows beyond any upper bound. So you can't find a single $N$ that will work for all $\epsilon$ values $\gt 0$. Which is what happens in your original question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence functions $\{f_n\}$ defined on $\mathbb{R^+}$ by
$$f_n(x) = \dfrac{1}{nx}$$
Now for a fixed $\epsilon > 0$, $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on the interval $[\epsilon, \infty)$ because $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| =  \frac{1}x|\frac{1}n - \frac{1}{m}| \leq $ $\frac{1}\epsilon |\frac{1}n - \frac{1}{m}|$ gets arbitrarily small for sufficiently large $n,m$ (i.e., $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence). But if you consider the interval $(0, \infty)$, where $1/x$ gets arbitrarily large, the choice of $n$ and $m$ depends on the value of $x$.